# How to use sqlite under ubuntu with teminal?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contacts

i just want to know how to get the android loacal-app Contact' database,i want to check the raw_contact or data  table with terminal.what tools i need or what is the orders?Thanks.

Comment: You will need ADB to issue the command adb shell, navigate to the data folder and there somewhere you should be able to find the database. Using emulator is fine as it is but if you are using a device it has to be rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question you want to use a CLI tool to inspect the Android contact's database. AFAIK the database itself should be located in

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

But could possibly change depending on the manufacture?

As far as using a local tool on your Ubuntu install you'd first need to get the platform SDK to use [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to pull the database off your device then use a local tool to manipulate or examine the database. **Note:Your device will need to be rooted to pull the database.**

For example on the SQLite website they provide a binary for Linux to inspect databases. It can be located here: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html but I'm sure there are a couple more floating around due to SQLite being an open standard.

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: thanks a lot!u're right,but i want to know how to use the sqlite,i try to enter sqlite> .tables and cann't get my expected result.

Comment: Did you load the database using it as the first parameter when opening sqlite?